# How to create delay between executions of a same Mono with reactor?

Tags: java, project-reactor

I have a service with a method that returns a Mono. Subscribing to this method launches some action that must be executed, but can be executed only 1 time per second maximum. So I'd like to force some delay between the executions.

I could encapsulate the behavior in a flux with delayElements, but:

- this flux could still be subscribed many times thus generating more that 1 action per second
- it's difficult (sometimes impossible) to batch calls in my usecase and pipelines gets hard to read

How can I better create a delay between executions of a same Mono? Is it even possible?

Thank you

##### EDIT: Attempt #2 calculating delay with number of currently delayed actions

I'm thinking about an other solution, with some logic to follow currently delayed actions.

```
public class MyService {

  private Integer numberOfCurrentlyDelayedActions = 0;

  public Mono<String> doActionWithDelay(Data data) {
    increaseNumberOfCurrentlyDelayedActions();
    return Mono.just(data)
      .delayElement(calculateNeededDelay())
      .flatMap(this::doAction)
      .doAfterTerminate(this::decreaseNumberOfCurrentlyDelayedActions);
  }

  private Duration calculateNeededDelay() {
    int milliSecondDelay = 1000 * (numberOfCurrentlyDelayedActions - 1);
    log.info("nb of currently delayed actions {} and associated delay {}", numberOfCurrentlyDelayedActions, milliSecondDelay);
    return Duration.ofMillis(milliSecondDelay);
  }

  private void increaseNumberOfCurrentlyDelayedActions() {
    numberOfCurrentlyDelayedActions = numberOfCurrentlyDelayedActions + 1;
  }

  private void decreaseNumberOfCurrentlyDelayedActions() {
    log.info("action done");
    numberOfCurrentlyDelayedActions = numberOfCurrentlyDelayedActions - 1;
    log.info("now nb of delayed actions after act {}", numberOfCurrentlyDelayedActions);
  }
}
```

The issue here is that running locally, displayed logs makes no sense (count is sometimes negative, number of currently delayed actions not incrementing/decrementing correctly etc). But the following test is working properly.

```
@Test
void should_delay_action_when_many_actions_are_sent_at_the_same_time() {
  var milliSecondDurationBetweenActions = 1000;
  var data = generateData();
  //returned by myService.doAction;
  when(myOtherService.doAction(any())).thenReturn(Mono.just("responseId"))

  var result = Flux.just(1, 2, 3).flatMap((__) - > myService.doActionWithDelay(data));

  StepVerifier.withVirtualTime(() - > result)
    .expectNextCount(1)
    .thenAwait(Duration.ofMillis(milliSecondDurationBetweenActions))
    .expectNextCount(1)
    .thenAwait(Duration.ofMillis(milliSecondDurationBetweenActions))
    .expectNextCount(1)
    .verifyComplete();
}
```

So is the code supposed to work (aka logs are broken due to asynchronicity)?

And still, is there a better way to create delay when calling many times the same mono?

##### EDIT2: Attempt #2-bis calculating delay with number of currently delayed actions with Atomic object

Well, let's say it was not working, because now with an AtomicInteger logs are working properly. (actually not, see edit3)

```
public class MyService {

  private AtomicInteger numberOfCurrentlyDelayedActions = new AtomicInteger(0);

  public Mono<String> doActionWithDelay(Data data) {
    return Mono.just(data)
      .delayElement(calculateNeededDelayAndIncreaseNumberOfDelayedActions())
      .flatMap(this::doAction)
      .doAfterTerminate(this::decreaseNumberOfCurrentlyDelayedActions);
  }

  private Duration calculateNeededDelayAndIncreaseNumberOfDelayedActions() {
    var nbOfDelayedActionsExceptCurrent = numberOfCurrentlyDelayedActions.incrementAndGet() - 1;
    int milliSecondDelay = 1000 * nbOfDelayedActionsExceptCurrent ;
    log.info("nb of currently delayed actions {} and associated delay {}", nbOfDelayedActionsExceptCurrent, milliSecondDelay);
    return Duration.ofMillis(milliSecondDelay);
  }

  private void decreaseNumberOfCurrentlyDelayedActions() {
    log.info("action done");
    var nbOfDelayedActions = numberOfCurrentlyDelayedActions.decrementAndGet();
    log.info("now nb of delayed actions after act {}", nbOfDelayedActions);
  }
}
```

And still, is there a better way to create delay when calling many times the same mono?

##### EDIT3: The desillusionment

This is not working, when launching many actions, as there are overlaps when one ends :')

##### EDIT4

##### Attempt #2-ter calculating delay with number of currently delayed actions with Atomic object and a Scheduler

Launching automatically the decrease with a scheduler, instead of launching at the end of an action, works. But it checks to decrease even when it is not usefull. I suppose that all theses checks at a high rate (1 check per second) is not a good idea.

##### Attempt #3 calculating delay with last execution time and Atomic object

I've developped an other solution, based on next supposed execution date, and transforming it back to delay comparing with now. This gets rid of the scheduler. It generates an other issue due to calculation time and time to be scheduled. So actions tend to be randomly spaced by less than 1s.

##### Attempt #4 publishing and consuming an infinite sink

Now I'm thinking about listening to a sink (which can be used as a flux and have delayElements) which never ends, and pushing incoming actions to execute in the sink.

```java
public class MyService {

  private final Sinks.Many<Data> actionsToLaunch = Sinks.many().unicast().onBackpressureBuffer(
    Queues.<Data>unboundedMultiproducer().get());

  public MyService() {
    waitForFutureActionsAndLaunchThemWithCustomSchedule();
  }

  public Mono<String> doActionWithDelay(Data data) {
    return Mono.just(data)
      .doOnNext(this::addToActionsToLaunch)
      .map(Data::name);
  }

  private void waitForFutureActionsAndLaunchThemWithCustomSchedule() {
    actionsToLaunch.asFlux()
      .delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(1000))
      .flatMap(data - > doAction(data).onErrorResume(err - > {
        log.error("Error execution action {}", data, err);
        // a better error handling can be done
        return Mono.empty(); // prevent from closing the subscription
      }))
      .subscribe();
  }

  private void addToActionsToLaunch(Data data) {
    // a better error handling can be done, not using emitNext
    actionsToLaunch.emitNext(data, Sinks.EmitFailureHandler.busyLooping(Duration.ofMinutes(5)));
  }
}
```

I'm still unsure whether this is a good solution, or not, as I don't know if the flux will automatically close (for inactivity? or something else) and if an infinite flux, as here, can generate bad side effects (memory issues, locks, thread issues etc)